# Custom OpenID for Sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, openid

On the Ubuntu Stack Exchange site it would be really useful to be able to have a 'custom' default OpenID provider, so the Stack Exchange site can be used with the same login that Ubuntu users are used to using for other Ubuntu sites (e.g. bugtracker, forums, etc).

Would StackExchange be willing to support this?

[Launchpad Single Sign On](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/209/launchpad-single-sign-on)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now implemented, so it is possible to have per-site lists of openid providers.

Comment: Could [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/638/14) get implemented then? Should I open a new request for it?

Answer (score 3):

Same for [gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), e.g. [Can Steam be added as an OpenID provider?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/638/can-steam-be-added-as-an-openid-provider)